# IronPDF in Unity3D

Tags: .net, security, unity-game-engine, mono

When i try to use the IronPDF .NET library inside unity3d it results in a SecurityException saying "couldn't impersonate token".

the same happens when i use the library in a console app if i run it with mono, but works fine when i run it normally.

the library should be platform apathetic as it says on their website, so is there a way to achieve that as it might be the only free option.

I'm using a local html file to produce the pdf

```
var Renderer = new IronPdf.HtmlToPdf();
 var PDF = Renderer.RenderHTMLFileAsPdf("new.html");
 var OutputPath = "out.pdf";
 PDF.SaveAs(OutputPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and got in touch with the IronPDF developers, here is the answer: 
**"Currently Unity 3D isn't supported by IronPDF but it is something we plan on releasing for out next update."**